# choosing processing extent from a polygon in a feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extents

I am currently trying to convert a list of polygons to individual rasters. Using Arcgis Desktop's 'convert polygon to raster', this is rather simple. But since the polygons are rather spread out, each time i create a raster (for 1 polygon), it uses the entire extent of the feature class, which means the resulting raster is unnecessarily big (with many nodata cells).

I was therefore wondering, if its possible to choose the specific polygon's extent, instead of choosing all polygons' extents? I have tried extracting each separate polygon beforehand, but it seems a bit slow.

I will try to implement the entire analysis (which is a bit longer) in arcpy afterwards, so if the solution is easier to find in there, that might help aswell.

edit: I think i might i have been vague in my description. I mean i have a feature class containing multiple polygons. is there a way to select the extent of one of these polygons? right now i can only select layers (i.e. the feature class and all of its polygons), not separate polygons in the feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the environments you can set the processing extent to each individual polygon. You will have to do this each time you convert from polygon to raster.

Geoprocessing tab> Environments> Processing Extent> Select the polygon you want to convert to a raster

Hope this helps

Comment: I think i might i have been vague in my description. I mean i have a feature class containing multiple polygons. is there a way to select the extent of one of these polygons? right now i can only select layers (i.e. the feature class and all of its polygons), not separate polygons in the feature class.

Comment: Depending on the number of polygons you have. It may be simplest to select the polygon you wish to set the extent too and export the data to a new layer. To do this Select the data>right click on the layer containing the data> select export data> change the option to selected data>save. After you have completed this you would then follow my original instructions.